# Android Studio Error : String index out of range: -124

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.2 and when I'm creating a signed apk the building process stops with the error in Event Log

```
`ExternalSystemException: String index out of range: -124`
```

and the it prompts to send a error report and it contains  following detais

```
String index out of range: -124
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: String index out of range: -124
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:238)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.invokeGradleTasks(GradleTasksExecutor.java:416)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.run(GradleTasksExecutor.java:222)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
```

so how can I fix this. thanks and regards.

Comment: Searching stackoverflow shows me that most probably you are missing one (or several) translations from your international strings.xml files

Comment: I didn't use translations.... my app supports only for English. thanks